# keeping ice cream fresh for 12 hours while transporting

Tags: ice-cream

Is it possible to keep it fresh during a long distance travel by train? Normal styrofoam boxes won't work I guess, what about thermos flasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My dad used to buy icecream after a long day work for us (it was a 3 hour drive.) 
He used styrofoam boxes with some dry ice. Not sure if it can hold up till 12 hours.

Comment: Yup, dry ice is the key. To make it last longer, use more dry ice (and the best-quality ice chest you can fit in your luggage).

Comment: Hadn't thought about dry ice. Sounds good, thanks.